# Match and delete lines with ~100 strings

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I have a list of roughly 100 entries to be deleted from a csv-delimited file. They are already in another text file called 'tbd.txt;

My first thought is to write a bash for loop around 'sed -i' but that seems horribly wasteful of disk i/o.

Is there a better way to have sed parse the file of deletions internally? There is a [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12894762/1546909) but the solution doesn't seem scalable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide us with i) an example of your input data (both files) and desired output ii) an explanation of your data. Can you have things like `field1, "field2A,field2B"`?  can your fields contain newlines? How about wildcards? iii) do you want to remove the entire line for each match or only a specific field?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to process tbd.txt and create a sed script from it which would delete the lines. Something like

```
sed 's=^=/=;s=$=/d=' tbd.txt | sed - file.csv
```